# My navbar gets stacked vertically in mobiles. I want it to be horizontal in one line

Tags: html, css

On clicking on the below link, you will see that the navbar gets stacked vertically one above another in a mobile. I want it to be in one single line in the same mobile.

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=localhost%2FAssignment%2520App%2Fbasic.html%23

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap bro.

Comment: created a code snippet of your code. please tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: I want a horizontal navbar on mobiles and not a vertical one. Click the below link to know what I am saying. Please don't downvote the question.  

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=localhost%2FAssignment%2520App%2Fbasic.html%23

Comment: @Mithilesh Bhutada your link is not workng

Comment: Your link is passing in a localhost address as a parameter, so only you will be able to see whatever you're linking to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to delete `sm` from `navbar-expand-sm`. So it will only be `navbar-expand`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you make my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfc4k16o/1/) smaller you can see it. `navbar-expand-sm` means that it will become collapse when it's on a small screen. You can change `sm` to -md, -lg or -xl. this stands for screen size reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer, you beat me to it, defo the easiest and I think correct way to solve the problem

Comment: @Brad Yes I think it's too.

Comment: What does navbar-expand-sm mean @xmaster??

Comment: @MithileshBhutada `navbar-expand-sm` means that it will become collapse when it's on a small screen. You can change sm to -md, -lg or -xl. this stands for screen size reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's wrapping to vertical is because there is a breakpoint at 576 pixel width that changes the `flex-direction` property so that it's set to `row` when the viewport width is greater than 576 pixels and `column` when it is less.

If you need to fix this with just CSS then you can do this with a simple override.

```css
.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav{
  flex-direction:row;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link{
  padding-right:0.5rem;
  padding-left:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

However the best way is probably to simply remove the `sm` from `navbar-expand-sm` (as pointed out by xmaster) which will mean this rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Overide the flex-direction

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
/* delete this 
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
*/
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```